# matplotlib: manually change yaxis values to differ from the actual value (NOT: change ticks!)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to create a plot with matplotlib where the displayed values on the y-axis are the positive value of a negative number although the number is negative. (I don't want to just change the ticks!)

A bit more specific: I have the following sample code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([
    [0,1,-2,-3],
    [4,4,-3,-5],
    [2,1,-3,-2],
    [4,2,-6,-5],
    [4,4,-6,-5],
    [7,5,-4,-2],
    [6,5,-4,-3]])
df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']    
df.plot(kind='area', y=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], color=['k', 'grey', 'r','g'])
plt.title('Testplot')
plt.xlabel('X label')
plt.ylim(-10,10)
#plt.yticks( --- what do I need to do here? ---)
plt.ylabel('Y label')
plt.show()
```

[image: Here is the plot.]

Now, in the plot I want colums 'c' and 'd' (with negative numbers) to be displayed below the x axis, as the plot shows. BUT I want the y axis to tell their positive values.
(The four columns measure real things and are just split for visualization reasons, so a negative measurement on the y axis of, say -5 bananas eaten, doesn't make sense.)

(I do NOT want to have all four columns displayed over the x axis! I want the graph to look like it does except the y axis displayed values (not range!) to be displaying manual values, specifically to show - from top to bottom: 10, 9, 8, ...2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ... 7, 8, 9, 10)

Is that possible and can someone drop a hint how to do that? Many thanks in advance and all the best!

Comment: The only solution to this *is*  to change the ticks. For how to do it, see duplicate.

Comment: Okay, that's sad. Sorry for creating a duplicate then.

Comment: You don't need to be sorry. Duplicates can also be useful for future readers, who may then find a solution easier using the wording used in this post, instead of the other.